# Device failure probability with expected value

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

The expected value of a device's failure during 1000 workhours is 5. Find the probability of a device failure during 20 workhours.

I don't know how to even start this assignment. Finding the expected value of a failure during 20 workhours is easy, but to find the probability... I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint 1**

Probability of success in one workout is eqal to $p(s)=1- \frac{5}{1000} = 0.995$

**Hint 2**

Probability of succeses in all 20 workouts is equal to $p(A)=p(s)^{20}$